# Trying to make a pure jquery/javascript chatbot; Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I'll try to keep this as short as possible: This is my first ever attempt of coding something from scratch and alone so please forgive any stupid mistakes made, this also my first ever poste on this site so sorry for bad formatting too.

Onto my problem: I'm trying to make a purely Javascript-based chatbot of sorts, as a proof-of-concept (and bragging rights of course).

I managed to get the basics to work, like checking the answer on enter keypress and a basic input/output system (this took me 2 days, like I said I'm a beginner) but a key feature I'm missing is a continuous chat with branching questions, I of course tried using Arrays filled wit strings at first but then opted for basic 'If/else' like you see in the added .js, the key PROBLEM here is the 'checkAnswer2' function! I can't seem to figure out where the logic problem is! The booleans part SHOULD work afaik! Please help me debug this mess of a code.

EDIT;
Ok, so the Syntax error has been fixed thanks to a kind commenter (Thanks dude!) but there's still some kind of logical error here because the function still doesn't work as intended. :/

EDIT 2.0;
Ok so apparently I somehow missed a quite essential snipbit of the HTML, fixed the problem now and ran the code as posted here so it should work now. (Except, of course, the problem stated above)

```js
$("#answerField").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#javascriptButton").click();
    }
});
   

function updateit() {
 var answer = output;
 document.getElementById('story').innerHTML = answer;
};
var output = 'Question';
updateit(); 



document.getElementById('javascriptButton').onclick = function interpretAnswer() {
 var inputResults = document.getElementById('answerField').value;
   answer = inputResults.toUpperCase();
   checkAnswer();
   
 };
 
 function checkAnswer() {
    if (answer === "YES") { 
     output = 'YESANS';
    }
    else if (answer === "NO") {
      output = "NOANS";
    }
    else if (answer === 'MAYBE') { 
      output = "MAYBEANS" ;
    }
    else {
      
      output = ("Please pick a valid answer");
    };
    updateit();
  };

<!-- THIS function is what causes problems! (I fixed the syntax here, the error I made is kind of embarrasing -->
   
 function checkAnswer2() {
  if (output === 'YESANS' && answer === 'YES2') {
          output = 'YESANS2';
       }
          else if (output === "MAYBEANS" && answer === 'MAYBE2') {
           output = 'MAYBEANS2';
           }
  
  if (output === 'YESANS' && answer === 'YESANS2') {
      output = 'YESOUT';
   }
      else if (output === "MAYBEANS" && answer === 'MAYBEANS2') {
       output = 'MAYBEOUT';
       }
  
      else if (output === 'NOANS' && answer === 'NOANS2') {
       output = 'NOOUT';
      }
      else {output = "error"}
       updateit();
      };
```

```css
<!-- I only included the CSS for completion purposes only, it's not relevant whatsoever -->


<style>

header { margin-right: 50px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1; margin-top: 1px; padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;}

body { margin-left: 20px; top: 50px; background-color: powderblue; font-family: arial; }

input { margin-left: 50px; top: 150px; display: block; padding: 10px; font-size: 14pt; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; }

#list { margin-left: 90px}

#javascriptButton {opacity: 0; margin-left: 900px; top: 50px; padding: 1px; font-size: 1pt; margin-top: 25px; }

#listhead {font-family: 'arial'; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 45px; margin-left: 60px}

</style>
```

```html
<DOCTYPE!>
<html><body>

<header id="story">Question</header>
 

<input id="answerField" name="number" placeholder='Answer' type=”text” onKeydown=”Javascript: if (event.keyCode == 13) checkAnswer(); updateit();”>




           <div id="listhead">
           Possible Answers;
           </div>
           <div id="list">
           <ul><li> 
           Yes</li><li>
           No</li><li>
           Maybe
           </li></ul></div>
           
           
           
<button id="javascriptButton">Submit Answer</button>


<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head> 



</body></html>
```

Comment: You have elements like `story` that don't even exist in your HTML. The only way to check what is wrong here would be reproducing your state and going after the errors. This is not possible due to an uncomplete testcase.

Comment: I was stupid again. But it was a simple copy/paste error so please don't think I'm too stupid. If you type Yes, No or Maybe and then press enter it should validate the answer and onput the default answer I assigned to it!

Comment: If you solved your question and think it could help others - feel free to answer your own question and except it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `else` statement with a condition. This should be an `else if`.

```
else if (output === 'NOANS' && answer === 'NO2') 
{
    output = 'NOANS2';
}
```

Comment: Ok so after I fixed the syntax error (thanks for the help, seriously.) I have a logical error in the code. The function doesnt make my code useless now though if included, so there's that! Progress has been made. :3